# What type of chemical reaction is this?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

So far we have learned about about single displacement, double displacement, gas evolving, neutralization, synthesis, disassociation, and combustion.

I was trying to solve the following chemical equation and I couldn't figure out under what category this reaction falls.

*Aqueous lithium hydroxide reacts with gaseous carbon dioxide to produce aqueous lithium hydrogen carbonate.

$$\ce{LiOH(aq) + CO2(g) -> LiHCO3(aq)}$$

If this is a synthesis, how can the base combine with $\ce{CO2}$?

Comment: @santimirandarp Of course, you could have edit this yourself.

Comment: Chemical reactions don't really have types.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of describing this reaction, but the word that comes to mind is *addition*, because $\ce{OH^-}$ adds to $\ce{CO_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Lewis theory would suggest it to be an acid-base:
CO2 behaves as electron pair acceptor from OH-

[image]

However, it is not compulsory to classify a reaction into just one type:
The given reaction could also be called synthesis, as simpler molecules combine to give a more complex one.